# Using liferay with external content source

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I want to use liferay as a website layout management tool, but not use its cms features to store content. Example: Configuring a news website structure on a liferay instance (pages, groups, etc), but fetch the news from a webservice exposed by a 3rd party application.

Is such integration supported in liferay, or should i pick another solution that fits better ?

Thx for help =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I dont see a problem in using it. It satisfies your requirement and has more. You leave what you dont want to use.

There are other CMS integrations are already proven such as Alfresco. Webservice invocation is just another SOAP/Rest API calls which is natively supported.